# pointer to pointer to and pointer to arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

could someone give me a brief explanation of what is happening differently in the functions below?

```
    void f1(data_t **d)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
        {
            (*d)[i].ival = i;
        }
    }

    void f2(data_t **d)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
        {
            (*d)->ival = i;
            (*d)++
        }
    }

    void f3(data_t *d)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
        {
            d->ival = i;
            d++;
        }
    }

    void f4(data_t *d)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
        {
            d[i].ival = i;
        }
    }
```

particularly what is happening differently in f2.  but clearly different things are happening in each.

f1 and f3 do the same thing (but differently). f2 fails completely, and f4 is buggy (works in this example, but when i tried to put other values into other pointers (char *) the strings end up strange.)

Comment: how about you explain what YOU think is happening....

Comment: naw... actually... i have a interview and i'm just studying more about pointers and arrays...   the test before this interview had to deal with pointers to arrays of structs...  while figuring out code that works, i found that f1 and f3 works, f4 is buggy and f2 failed completely

Comment: On the basis that this probably is homework, I won't answer in detail; a hint would be that some of this code involves two different ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: @mat   sorry forgot a dot   >.>

Comment: @giorashc: You're not a Grim Reaper, so please don't use "all caps".

Comment: @Sun: f2 can't compile either.

Comment: @SigTerm haha I was just emphasizing loganfsmyth's point.

Comment: @giorashc: You can use **bold** and _italic_ text instead.

Comment: so... noone's gonna help me because you all think it's homework  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void f1(data_t **d)
{
    for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        (*d)[i].ival = i;
    }
}
```

The d seems to be a pointer to array of data_t's (or is a 1-element array of arrays of data_t). It is dereferenced to recover the array of data_t's and then i-th element of this array is modified.

```
void f2(data_t **d)
{
    for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        (*d)->ival = i;
        (*d)++
    }
}
```

This is a bit tricky and indeed does something different than in the first case. There was a pointer to array of data_t's. Here we have an array of pointers to data_t's. The pointer to first element is dereferenced to retrieve a pointer to data. Then -> is used to access the data and value is modified ( x->y = (*x).y ). Finally the pointer is moved to the next element of main array.

```
void f3(data_t *d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        d->ival = i;
        d++;
    }
}
```

Here we have simpler case, the d is just an array of data_t's accessed by pointer. Inside the loop, an element is accessed by ->, and then d is incremented to point to next element of array.

```
void f4(data_t *d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        d[i].ival = i;
    }
}
```

Similarly to f3, elements are modified by the [] operator.

Note the following facts:

```
int[] =(def) int *
```

if a is of type int * and i is of any integral type, then:

```
*(a + i) =(def) a[i]
```

Also, if a points to first element of an array, then

```
*a =(def) a[0]
```

and then, after a "a++"

```
*a =(def) a[1]
```

...and so on.

Comment: this is a huge help to my understanding!!!   what does (def) do in the above code?

Comment: =(def) equals to "means the same by definition", it is not an actual source code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take these one at a time:

```
// f1
(*d)[i].ival = i;
```

First, `(*d)` is dereferencing `d`, which appears to be a pointer to an array of `data_t` variables. This allows access to the actual array, such that `[i]` is accessing the `i`-th element of the array and assigning `i` to it.

```
// f2
(*d)->ival = i;
(*d)++;
```

`(*d)` is dereferencing `d` just like in the first one. However, there is one crucial bit of information about arrays that you should understand before moving on...

```
int j[2] = { 42, 50 };
int j0 = *j; // j0 is now 42
j += 1;
int j1 = *j; // j1 is now 50
```

Arrays are implemented as individual variables sequentially oriented in "slots" in memory, and an array is really just a pointer to the first slot. As such, `*j` is dereferencing `j`, which is currently pointing to the first element, resulting in `42`. Doing `j += 1` advances the pointer by one "slot", such that `*j` will now result in `50`.

Now, back to `f2`. `(*d)->ival` is exactly like doing `(**d).ival`. This is very much like the simple example I gave above. The next line, `(*d)++`, is advancing the pointer to the next "slot". Consider this simple diagram of what's "happening" in memory:

```
      +------+------+
      |*(j+0)|*(j+1)|
j --->|------|------|
      |  42  |  50  |
      +------+------+
```

with `j` pointing to the first "slot", the dereference shown in the first row, the value in the second.

`f3` is very much like `f2`, except that it expects the array to be passed as an argument, instead of a pointer to it. Hence, `d` only needs to be dereferenced once with the `->` operator (again, exactly like `(*d).ival`).

`f4`is very much like `f1`, except that it expects the array to be passed as an argument, instead of a pointer to it. Hence, `d[i]` is directly accessing the `i`-ith element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
 void f1(data_t **d) 
    { 
        for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++) 
        { 
            (*d)[i].ival = i; 
        } 
    }
```

1. You get a pointer to array `**d` of `data_t` ,which element is a structure,having a field `ival`
2. Access the array `*d`
3. Iterate all array elements,element by element,changing indices `i`.And updating `ival` of each array element by to be `i`

Note:You don`t change the pointer`*d`,pointing to array beginning

```
void f2(data_t **d) 
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++) 
    { 
        (*d)->ival = i; 
        (*d)++ 
    } 
}
```

1. You get a pointer to array `**d` of `data_t` ,which element is a structure,having a field `ival`
2. Access the array `*d`,which is also a pointer to the array (first element)
3. Updating `ival` of the (above) element by to be `i`,using pointer notation `(*d)->ival = i;`
4. Promote the pointer to the next array element `(*d)++` and return to `2.`From now on *d is
   pointing to the "sifted"array beginning.

   void f3(data_t *d)

   ```
   { 
      for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++) 
      { 
         d->ival = i; 
         d++; 
      } 
   }
   ```

   1.You get an array `*d` of `data_t` ,which element is sa structure,having a field `ival`.

   2.It also can be considered you get a pointer to the first element of array.
   Access access and update `ival` to be `i`,by pointer: `d->ival = i;`

   3.Promote the pointer to the next array element `d++`

   void f4(data_t *d)

   ```
   { 
      for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++) 
      { 
         d[i].ival = i; 
         d++; 
      } 
   }
   ```

As in `f3`.But you promote indices and update `ival` using reference notation (by value)

Comment: this is extremely helpful information with very clear explanations.